# inheritance constructor with no arg

Tags: java, inheritance, arguments

I am trying to create a no argument constructor that will take inputs from the user (via the Scanner class) for all of the instance variables, but it is inherited from another class.

How do I do this?

Here is what I did:

```
 public class Manager extends Super_Employee{
     String  manager ;

     /* String GetManger  (){
         return manager ;
     }*/

     Manager (){
        Scanner manager = new Scanner(System.in);
     }

     @Override
     String Print() {
         return ("the manager is : " +manager);
     }
```

here is the super class:

```
 public  class Super_Employee extends abstract_Employee {

     String Fname ;
     String Lname;
     String address;
     int number;
     Super_Employee(String Fname,String Lname, String address, int number)
    {
        System.out.println("Constructing an Employee");
        this.Fname = Fname ;
        this.Lname = Lname;
        this.address = address;
        this.number = number;
    }  


 @Override
    String Print (){
    return ("the employee name is : "+Fname+ " "+ Lname+ " ,the Employee address is  : "
            + address + " ,the employee Phone # : "+number);   
} 
}
```

Comment: constructor Super_Employee in class pkgabstract.employee.Super_Employee cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Sounds like `Super_Employee` does not have no-arg constructor. Does it?

Comment: What are you doing that's causing that exception? I don't see anything in your code that calls `super(String,String,String,int)`

Comment: Did you provide a non arg constructor (default constructor) in the superclass? You must provide one when you have a default constructor in a subclass.

Comment: @JonLin: super() is called implicitly in Manager(){...}

Comment: i dont have a default constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a no-arg constructor in `Super_Employee`

```
Super_Employee() { }
```

Since, you have

```
Super_Employee(String Fname,String Lname, String address, int number) {
    //...
```

the compiler doesn't provide a default constructor (which is a no-arg constructor provided by the constructor itself).

Comment: it works :) , but this line gives an error Scanner manager = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: @MichaelShokery: Change the variable `manager` in the constructor to something else like `scanner`.

Comment: @MichaelShokery: That's because you have an instance variable `String  manager;`. And the local variable `Scanner manager` within the constructor hides it.

Answer (score 2):

You MUST provide a default constructor in your subclass when in it you need to define a default constructor that will not call a non default constructor in the superclass. Confusing? Take a look in the example.

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo( String x ) {
    }
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    public Bar() {
        super(); // this is called implicitly even if this line is not provided! compilation error here
    } 
}
```

In the example above, the subclass construtor will call super(), the default constructor of the subclass, so you must provide a defualt construtor in the superclass or write your subclass this way:

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
    public Bar() {
        super( "hadoken!" ); // now it works, since it calls a constructor that exists
    } 
}
```

Now, if you don't provide any constructor in the Foo class, it will have a defaul constructor (provided by the compiler).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your errors it sounds like your super class takes 3 arguments, but you're trying to use the default constructor since you don't have the values for those three values yet. In this case I would recommend using a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Encapsulation) to construct your object.

Example:

```
public class Manager extends Super_Employee{

    /** Factory method, reading constructor arguments from System.in */
    public static Manager make() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        new Manager(s.next(), s.next(), s.next(), s.nextInt());
    }

    public Manager(String fName, String lName, String address, int number) {
        super(fName, lName, address, number);
    }

     // . . .
```

Using the factory method `Manager.make()` to construct your object allows you to read in all the values you need from `System.in` before calling the super constructor, which wouldn't be possible from within the `Manager` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Some Possible options:

1) use a static builder

```
public static Manager newManager() {

 .....

return new Manager(.....);
```

2) create no-args super constructor:

```
Super_Employee() {
   ...
}}
```

3) Could use a "Second class" - rather ugly and I do no advise

```
public Manager() {
  this(new MyTemp());
}

public Manager(MyTemp temp) {
  super(temp.fname, temp.lname,....);
}
```